# Retrieve Hibernate Search results directly from Lucene Index

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

How can I execute a search using Hibernate Search that will NOT retrieve the actual entities from the database and will instead just return the Document cache records for these entities? I am making sure to store the fields that I need inside the index. The database will be active and available during this process, I just wanted to decrease the unnecessary load.

```
@Column
@Field (index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES)
private String title;

@Id
@Column
@DocumentId
@Field (store = Store.YES)
private String guid;

Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
FullTextSession fts = org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(sess);
//returns matching Articles from database, how would I retrieve only the index records?
Query query = fts.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Article.class);
```

Versions:

Hibernate Search 4.1.1.Final

Hibernate Core 4.1.6.Final

Lucene 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the Projection feature of Hibernate Search as described in the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections).
The key is to call *query.setProjection* with the list of field names you want to retrieve from the index. Something like:

```
query.setProjection( "field1", "field2", "field3" );
```

Note though that as a result you will get object arrays and not managed Hibernate entities.